# Run eureka service in a docker container

Tags: java, spring, docker, netflix-eureka, netflix

I want to run `eureka-server` as container and want to let other microservices register to this container later on. But I got some issues to let it run as container and access it. The application is running in STS without issues. When I execute it in STS I can access the `eureka-server` using `localhost:8761`.

`application.java:`

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`application.yml:`

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

`bootstrap.yml:`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-service
```

`Dockerfile:`

```
FROM java:8 
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","- 
jar","/app.jar"]
```

`pom.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <docker.image.prefix>microservice</docker.image.prefix>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId} 
 </repository>
                    <buildArgs>

 <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                    <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka- 
server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Finchley.M8</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

`What am I doing:`

- running `mvn package && java -jar target/eureka-service-0.1.0.jar` to build
  the jar. During this the spring boot application and I have to stop this 
  using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. The image has been created in the `target` folder.
- building image using `mvn install dockerfile:build`. Image has been built.
- run the created image using `docker run -p 8080:8080 -t microservice/eureka- 
  service`
- This is the response of the docker bash:

  `2018-03-23 15:28:05.618  INFO 1 --- [           main]`
   `hello.EurekaServiceApplication           : Started`
   `EurekaServiceApplication`
   `in 17.873 seconds (JVM running for 19.066)`
   `2018-03-23 15:29:05.475  INFO 1 --- [a-EvictionTimer]`
   `c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with`
   `compensationTime 0ms`

The notification `2018-03-23 15:31:05.476  INFO 1 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 1ms` returns by the bash about once a minute.
If I try to call the `eureka-server`using `192.168.99.100:8080` in the browser it says I can't access this page. 
When I end the application using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> I can view all running containers and the bash tells me the container `microservice/eureka-service` is still running. Still can not access it tho.

Comment: what if i want to run multiple replicas of eureka service as a container for high availability? is there a doc explains that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
server:
  port: 8761
```

You have that in your application.yml. Which means the application is running on port `8761` not `8080`

You should try `docker run -p 8761:8761 -t microservice/eureka-service`

Answer (score 0):

As this is getting some views: 
`port forwarding` is an option too. 
As the port is:

```
server:    
    port:8761
```

you can also forward it to `port 8080`, which is a very common port for tutorials and lectures:

```
docker run -p 8761:8080 -t microservice/eureka-service
```

Comment: How to make container port 8080 and it exactly listens to port 8761 inner application?   
This is wrong you must make it ```8080:8761```
So container port is 8761 and world port 8080 that any microservice can connect to it.