# Eureka services giving Request execution error?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, netflix-eureka

Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/} is giving when I am running in docker windows but It is registering with eureka server when I am running in spring boot app in STS.

for server i run in docker
    docker run -p 8761:8080 serverimagename
    for services I run in docker
    docker run -p 8762:8080 servicesimagename
    server app.properties

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled= true
#eureka.instance.statusPageUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}:${eureka.instance.secure-port}
#eureka.instance.service-url.defaultZone: https://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
and services app.properties
spring.application.name=demo1
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.jsp
```

ERROR 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:529) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:102) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:846) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1405) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Comment: When you are working with docker you need to change localhost to container name here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486460/connection-refused-by-spring-boot-app-running-in-different-docker-container/53487923#53487923

Comment: Buy every time when I will run then every time container name will be change.. But I am not. That much aware of docker. Is it possible when I will. run Image that time I can set container name..

Comment: as you told same way I did but same error..?can you show examplecode

Comment: OK I'll help you but can you share your code on some repo?

Comment: sir it is simple eureka repositery code and properties I had share above

Comment: Yes but I wanna see how you are implementing it. How many microservices do you have? Are you using docker-compose? What is container name which you wanna use? And please don't post your code on the answers! Edit the above question that you did.

Comment: Right now for testing I am using one and I am not using docker compose.I am not using container name I am using random container and that name I am using it in microservice defaultZone and then again making doker image of services.

Comment: Okay this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453397/run-eureka-service-in-a-docker-container will help you

Answer (score 2):

For STS:
I was getting the same error, My mistake was I had both configuration files-
`application.properties` and `application.yml`
in the eureka server project/microservice.
(added as part of experiment but got lost)
When I removed `application.yml` then it started working all fine.
application.properties has these working entries

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MicroServicesClient1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroServicesClient1Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("MicroServiceClient1");
    }

}
```

Comment: my controller here

Answer (score 0):

For me the error

> Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

occured because I was starting the Eureka client service while I forgotten to start the Eureka discovery server.

Run the discovery server if not started yet and see the result

Answer (score -2):

Please check your eureka Server is up and running ..

it is very similar to ERROR 19840 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server