# What are these Spring Cloud errors in AWS?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a Spring cloud deployment in AWS, consisting of Spring Cloud (Server), Spring Boot (client) that acts like all connections are there.  However the log files are full of these messages on each server:

> INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec
> : I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when
> processing request to
> {}->http://xxxxx-ALB-123456789.us-east-x.elb.amazonaws.com:8010: The
> target server failed to respond
>
> INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0]  o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec
> : Retrying request to
> {}->http://xxxxx-ALB-123456789.us-east-x.elb.amazonaws.com:8010
>
> INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0]  c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver
> : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
>
> 2022-12-20 18:13:37.828  INFO 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0]
> c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error.
> endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{
> serviceUrl='http://eureka:@xxxxx-ALB-123456789.us-east-x.elb.amazonaws.com:8010/eureka/}
> exception=I/O error on PUT request for
> "http://eureka:@xxxxx-ALB-123456789.us-east-x.elb.amazonaws.com:8010/eureka/apps/DRUG-SERVICE/drug-service:9a1dda708e094daea4750f050402536c":
> xxxxx-ALB-123456789.us-east-x.elb.amazonaws.com:8010 failed to
> respond; nested exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException:
> xxxxx-ALB-123456789.us-east-x.elb.amazonaws.com:8010 failed to respond
> stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O
> error on PUT request for
> "http://eureka:@xxxxx-ALB-123456789.us-east-x.elb.amazonaws.com:8010/eureka/apps/DRUG-SERVICE/drug-service:9a1dda708e094daea4750f050402536c":
> xxxxx-ALB-123456789.us-east-x.elb.amazonaws.com:8010 failed to
> respond; nested exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException:
> xxxxx-ALB-123456789.us-east-x.elb.amazonaws.com:8010 failed to respond
>
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)

Again, I cannot tell that anything is wrong since these appear to be INFO level logging events.  However, before I set

```
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient=FATAL
```

I would like to make sure I will not be masking an issue that I should not be.

** UPDATE **
Since these appear to be INFO level messages I thought I would mask these:

```
INFO 1 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
INFO 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ ...
```

With these in my application.properties file:

> logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http=FATAL
> logging.level.com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator = FATAL
> logging.level.com.netflix.discovery.shared.resolver.aws = ERROR

However, they are still filling up my log files.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: The issue you might be masking is the fact that this request is not returning:
`PUT http://eureka:@xxxxx-ALB-123456789.us-east-x.elb.amazonaws.com:8010`
This is your service trying to register itself with [Eureka](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-netflix) server. If you are not using Eureka, then you should remove `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` from your dependencies.

Comment: I have a Eureka server and each micro service uses eureka-client.  I see them all registered on the Eureka dashboard, and all my requests return successfully.

Comment: Interesting. Is the host name in the failing request the same one where your Eureka server is running? Maybe it is trying this URI, and after failing, switching to a fallback (which is working).

Comment: Yes, the hostname is provided in the EC2 task definition, which is the same ALB url that I use to view the Eureka dashboard

Comment: This question might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959448/eureka-services-giving-request-execution-error